# Use ANTLR in Windows Phone project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, antlr

I have a grammar file and use ANTLR to generate the grammar to C#. I added the `Antlr3.Runtime.dll` and the `.cs` files to my Windows Phone project. However, if I declare any object in the `Antlr3.Runtime` namespace, I get the following exception:

```
Failure has occurred while loading a type.
```

Are there any solution for this? Can Windows Phone 7.5 (or even 8.0) utilize ANTLR?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, ANTLR does not currently support Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Joel Martinez got one compiled as part of his work on JINT.

Here's the [github](https://github.com/joelmartinez/Jint.Phone) link.